# If statements not working with user inputted char = char

Tags: c++

I was doing a drill from my textbook and have been having trouble with it.   here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
string name;
string friend_name;
char friendsex;
char m = 'm';
char f = 'f';

cout << "Enter the name of the person you would like to write to" << endl;
cin >> name;
cout << endl << "Dear " << name <<", " 
    << endl 
    << endl 
    << "Hey how are you? I myself have been fine recently. I've been wanting to do some catching up with you"
    << endl
    << endl
    << "Please enter the name of a friend now"
    << endl;
cin >> friend_name;  
cout << endl << "Hey how are you? I myself have been fine recently. I've been wanting to do some catching up with you. Have you seen " << friend_name << " recently?" << endl << endl;
cout << "Please enter the sex of your friend (m/f)"
    <<endl;
cin >> friendsex;

if(friendsex = 'm'){
    cout << "If you have, could you please tell him to call me?";
}
else if(friendsex = 'f'){
    cout << "If you have, could you please tell her to call me?";
}
return 0;
}
```

I cant figure out how to make the if statements work with the user inputted char. It always runs the male statement even if i enter f.

Comment: Turn on your compiler warnings. They're there to help you and save people time from having to answer questions that the compiler can answer, as well as the time it takes you to debug and finally ask.

Comment: `char friendsex` is funny...

Comment: they are on. the script runs and i get no errors. but the second if statement cannot run no matter what i enter.

Comment: @user2349335, Make sure you at least use `-Wall`. GCC gives this: *warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]* I'm pretty sure Clang's is like plain English.

Answer (score 4):

Use `==` rather than `=`. `=` assigns the right-hand side to the left-hand side and then evaluates the new value. In C++, any value other than 0 will evaluate to `true`, so your first if-statement always executes.

```
if(friendsex == 'm'){
    cout << "If you have, could you please tell him to call me?";
}
else if(friendsex == 'f'){
    cout << "If you have, could you please tell her to call me?";
}
```

Comment: i think i had them like this originally but changed them when i had problems with the compiler not recognizing the chars m and f because they were not declared so i changed it to = instead, not knowing what i was doing. noob mistake. After i added char declarations for m and f and changed it to == it runs like it should. Thanks!

Comment: @user2349335, It'll only complain if you use `friendsex == m` instead of `friendsex == 'm'`. The latter is a literal, which doesn't need to be declared.

Comment: @chris He did define `m` and `f` earlier in the program

Comment: ah ok. did not know adding ' ' would do that. thanks for the info!

Comment: @nullptr, From what I gathered, he didn't until after trying `friendsex == m`.

Comment: i declared them at the beginning but i did not know adding ' ' to the char in the if statement would make it so i didnt have to declare the chars in the beginning. It all works now.

Answer (score 1):

The first one gets run because you set `friendsex` to 'm'. `friendsex = 'm'` should be `friendsex == 'm'`. Same for 'f'.

Comment: why post an identical answer as nullptrs?

Comment: Because my page wasn't refreshed and didn't show his answer ;)

Comment: fair enough, then you get a +1 :-)

Answer (score 0):

if statements cant be executed by using "=" which is assignment operator. 
Use " == " for comparing

Answer (score -1):

Use == instead of = 
Don't use  'm; as I believe you are trying to use local variables.

if(friendsex == m){
    .............
}
else if(friendsex == f){
   .................
}

Comment: could you add a small amount of information as to why someone should use this?

Comment: Is it really that difficult to type `you`, `are`, and `to`?

Comment: For Max-
If you look at the code that was posted with this question

............
char m = 'm';
char f = 'f';
......

so the coder is actually trying/planning to use variables m and f

it's always better to use variable than hardcoded string fpor comparision...
if tomorrow the requirement changes  m="Male" and f="Female"... then only change is required at the very top part of code...

In-short its coding standard..